# css is not rendered properly

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to build a progress bar component where I want to achieve a specific design for that, as you can see how I tried it in this codesandbox link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-lamport-7zjvwj.

I want to achieve the following behavior:

- Initially, all dots should be blue except the first one which is rounded in blue.
- I want to keep the dots in the progress bar when I change the properties into blue if the percentage didn't cover them otherwise white

But somehow my CSS calculation is not working properly as expected which I believe I missed something, so any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is an error in line 60 et 61

```js
    const current = steps.indexOf(stepStatus); // issue here probably
    const step = steps.indexOf(stepStatus); // issue here probably
```

should be:

```js
    const current = steps.indexOf(progressBarStatus);
    const step = steps.indexOf(stepStatus)
```

In addition to this problem the width of the pourcentages is not accurate, you can fix this by changing the line 51 with:

```js
    const progressBarCalculatedWith =
      ((current / (getIntermediarySteps + 1)) * 100) + (steps.length -1 - current);
```

this is the result :

[working progress bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PAll.png)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the same calculation that calculates the % for the loading bar, then apply it ont he dots - So that if the value is 25% or more, then the first dot is blue, then an additional 25% and so on etc. It does not have to be interconnected with the rest of the loading bar, it can use the same calculation.

Simply an If / Else basically.

Comment: Could you please add code snippets for that or smth?

Comment: Recent update, I have tried the way you describe it but it didn't work unfortunatly

Comment: It does work, but you need to be the one that does it.
Here is an example of a box that becomes either filled or not filled depending on the value that is set in the y variable.

https://jsfiddle.net/xk0zgLh2/1/
If y is under 25, the box will remain not filled, if the y is equal to or over 25, the box is filled. Same logic can be applied on this dot.